# How to make a sticky ad on sidebar?

Tags: jquery, html, css, sidebar, sticky

Hi my website is http://cafun.cf 
I have a div containing an ad at the bottom of the sidebar. I want it to slide down when the user scrolls till it meets the footer.

I've tried many solutions using jquery, but its not working the right way (I don't know much jquery!)

This is the structure :

```
<aside> <!--other divs with 'asider' class -->
  <div class="asider">
     <div id="side_ad">
     <!-- Ad code-->
     </div>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Please help me with this... Thanks!

---

NOTE: I want the whole 'asider' class to  slide down.

Comment: jQuery isn't the tool for this - try CSS with the `position` as `fixed`.

Comment: @EvanKnowles but that doesn't work well-- the div should be fixed the moment the user begins scrolling past its top, and it shouldn't go beyond the sidebar (aside).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this

```
$stick = $('#marker');
jQuery(function($) {
  function fixDiv() {
    var $cache = $('#getFixed');
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $stick.offset().top)
      $cache.css({
        'position': 'fixed',
        'top': '10px'
      });
    else
      $cache.css({
        'position': 'relative',
        'top': 'auto'
      });
  }
  $(window).scroll(fixDiv);
  fixDiv();
});
```

Raplace the value of `$stick = $('#marker');` to the element that will trigger the fixed element or pixels. In any case there plenty of examples about fix a div on scroll

[Take a look at this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n3z23m6a/)

Answer (score 0):

#### Here is the CSS Way, DEMO : https://jsfiddle.net/9dvy5k46/

#### CSS

```
.asider {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:#dfdfdf;
    padding:100px 0;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
#side_ad {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:10px;
    right:5px;
    padding:50px;
    background:red;
    width:60px;
}
```